# Apart from speed, how do SSDs compare to HDDs?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I've heard that apart from straight-up speed, SSDs greatly outperform HDDs in power consumption and heat generation. How much greater, on average, is an SSD than an HDD in:

1. Power consumption.
2. Heat generation.

Is there a very significant difference?

Comment: Modern high performance SSDs (M.2 NVMe) have much higher power consumption, like 10 W.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a considerable difference in power consumption, I've seen different data on that, but its ~0.6W as opposed to ~2.2W.

One thing to keep in mind- because there is no queuing delay, the processor utilization will go up, and that will create a lot more heat.  A buddy of mine says that there are times where his laptop actually gets hotter after doing that upgrade for that reason.  I'm sure that only happens when he's really reading/writing a ton of data!

Comment: the processor utilization will go up in some cases (like upgrades) but for a shorter time. Because the amount of total CPU work shouldn't change. So higher peaks but less long. The actual result it depends on the function between the "density" (mix of phases of IO & CPU) of our example test load and the consumption of the CPU. Which depends on the power saving policy of the CPU and the OS

Answer (score 1):

Intel 520 SSD power consumption: 
Read/Write: 0.8w
Idle:       0.6w

WD Scorpio power consumption: 
Read/Write: 1.4w
Idle:       0.6w

There is not so much difference in the heat generation. They both produce heat in a same level.