# why do 2.5" ssd's use more power than 2.5" hdd's?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, power

I have a bunch of 2.5" HDDs. Their power requirements vary but it's usually in the range of 5V 0.6A - 0.85A (so 3 to 4.25 watts). RPM speed doesn't seem to play a huge factor nor does physical size, surprisingly (even 3.5" HDDs have similar power requirements). In fact, it seems like the biggest factor is capacity but idk.

2.5" SSDs, in contrast, have power requirements more along the lines of 5V 1.7A (or 8.5 watts). A NVM PCIe SSD that I have is 3.3V 2.8A (or 9.24 watts).

Overall, it seems like SSDs just have higher power requirements than HDDs and this seems counter intuitive to me.

Any ideas as to why this would be the case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Power consumption: SSD vs HDD](https://superuser.com/questions/589709/power-consumption-ssd-vs-hdd)

Comment: @TamalesRancheros - the first sentence of that question starts off with "_in websites everywhere it's noted that SSDs use much less power than HDDs_" and none of the answers seem to challenge that assertion. My observations, as detailed in my question, however, do seem to challenge that assertion. So, no, that's not an answer to my question - it just seems like another example of why my observations merit a question.

Comment: Modern SSDs draw more current that older ones. My Samsung Evo 850 1 TB (2.5" SSD) draws 0.045 W (that's 45 mW) when slumbering and around 2.6 W when doing a big bunch of sequential or random writes. A WD Blue  2.5" 500 GB HDD shows about 44 mW and 1.9 W for those states.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is almost certainly a question of *peak* power draw versus *average* power draw.

The figures on the outside of the drives are going to be the maximum power drawn at the worst case.

For the HDD this will be during motor startup, every time the drive spins up and down, and as you may have noticed this can take anywhere from half a second to a couple of seconds.  After that there will be a constant power draw required to keep the drive spinning. Once the drive decides it is not going to be used for a while then the drive will park the heads, the motor will turn off and you will be left with the power draw for the controller electronics.

For the SSD there may be the briefest of high currents on startup, as capacitors charge and electronics does its startup busy work, but it will be a much shorter time than the HDD. This should be a lot quicker than HDD startup times. After that it will fall back to its "idle" current draw which, due to the larger amount of electronic chips, be *slightly* higher than the HDD when it has parked the heads and turned the motor off, but not significantly higher.

The worst time for an SSD will be during drive block erasure and then sustained writes to the drive. Erases require a very large voltage to pull electrons off of the NAND cells to reset them, and a higher drive strength is required to write them. Reading will require a bit more power than idle, but not a massive amount.

But for writing the speed of an SSD works to its benefit. It can write a lot faster than an HDD and so spend a lot less time drawing higher power. It might briefly require a lot more current (the number printed on the label) but it will require that current for a massively reduced time.

The other factor is that a mechanical 2.5" drive in a laptop will potentially never spin down due to tiny reads happening here or there so it will be a constant power drain. The SSD has no large *constant* power drain.

So an SSD at average is probably in the same ballpark for power drawn as an HDD that has gone to sleep, perhaps a little higher but certainly not order of magnitude different. A HDD that is ready to work will definitely have a higher average power draw.

As a result SSDs can, despite having a higher *peak* current draw, have a much lower *average* current draw.

In short P=VA is only a useful equation when you know for certain that the current draw is constant. Most labelling will state **peak** draw because it determines what kind of PSU you get, but average draw is not mentioned.

Comment: In a similar vein, I remember an article discussing (possibly first or second gen) i3 vs i7... the i3 has a much lower Max TDP, but given a set workload, the i7 will actually complete it faster and return to idle sooner, resulting in a lower "_total power consumed_" figure for the higher rated / performance part.

Comment: @Attie I could believe that. I was tempted to mention that in CPUs there is an interesting parallel in what they were calling the "race to idle" a few years back. Clocking higher and do more work per clock might consume more power, but you can do it faster so you can spend less time *at* that higher clock. Then you can "back off" to a lower idle and in theory you can actually *save* power compared to a higher average clock speed. I wasn't too sure if it was *too* tangential to the point I was making about SSD vs HDD power draws...

Comment: That's exactly it! I forgot about the "_race to idle_" wording, similar in v. low power devices. I figured it was similar enough to mention (in terms of "_understanding power usage of modern electronics_") - a spinning hard disk is definately _not_ idle, and will stay in the "_higher power_" state for far longer than an SSD due to expecations around latencies and life expectancy. Also interesting to note that the rated power for each may not include the absolute peaks... when just spinning up, I wouldn't be surprised if mechanical disks exceed their rated specs, albeit for a "_brief_" period.

Comment: ... now I want to go and measure it ... [Start up Power Draw - 45drives.com](https://www.45drives.com/wiki/index.php?title=Start_up_Power_Draw)

Comment: @Attie indeed. During coil energisation you can have shockingly high currents, but you can manage it with an appropriate current limiting resistor to bring it back down to the realms of usefulness. I recently had reason to test a mains 240/110V transformer and we worked out that the input surge current (at 240V mind you) was in excess of 160 amps for a few handfulls of milliseconds, approx 10-20 milliseconds depending on where the in the AC cycle it was turned on at, before it settled down into a more normal current. The smaller coil in a hard disk shouldn't be *that* bad though.

Answer (score 1):

NVM PCIE SSD are power hungry, especialy faster ones. Regular SATA SSD use max 5V 0,5A. Typically about 2-3 times less than HDD.